# an example that the limit of a converging sequence is not unique

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

The following is an example that the limit of a converging sequence is not unique.

There are *uncountably* many numbers in Cantor Set.
Thus, there are *uncountably* many numbers in the segments in Cantor Set.
The length of each segment is the same.
Because the number of the endpoints of the segments is *countably* infinite, the number of the segments is *countably* infinite.
Thus, there has to be *more than finitely many* numbers in each segment even though the length of the segment is calculated as 0. Otherwise, it leads to a contradiction that finitely many numbers of *countably* infinite is *uncountably* infinite. Thus, there has to be *more than finitely many* numbers between the endpoints in each segment even though the length of the segment is calculated as 0.

Then, let’s consider a sequence of endpoint numbers in each step leading to one segment at its limit in Cantor Set. One may say that Cantor set has no “segments” because its length is 0. A “segment” is just a figurative term because there are endpoints and many internal points within each segment.
This sequence converges into that segment at its limit in Cantor Set. Even though the length of the segment is calculated as 0, there are ***more than finitely many*** numbers **between** the endpoint numbers in each segment at its limit. The endpoint numbers are the numbers in the sequence. Therefore, this sequence cannot lead to a single number even at its limit. Thus, a sequence of endpoint numbers in each step leading to one segment at its limit in Cantor Set converges, but its limit is not unique.■

I would like to get critical comments on this example.

Comment: "limit of a converging sequence is not unique" means what exactly?

Comment: Just because there are infinitely many numbers between any endpoints along the way doesn't mean there are infinitely many at the converging limit.  After all if you consider $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1{2^k}$ there will be an infinite number of points between any $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1{2^k}$ and $1$ but that doesn't man it has multiple limits.  Multiple limits is very clearly and obviously a cotradiction. If $L_1, L_2$ are limits by triangle inequality $|L_1 -a_n| + |L_2-a_n|\ge |L_1 -L_2| > 0$.

Comment: "there are more than finitely many numbers between the endpoint numbers in each segment at its limit" this is of absolutely zero relevance when considering limits.  A limit is not equal to any segment or point along the way and the fact that the steps along to way may be off the mark has utterly no bearing as to how the limit will behave.

Comment: However, my argument holds because Cantor set is not a set along the way but the limit set, and there are more than finitely many numbers between the endpoints in each segment in this limit set even though the length is calculated as 0. Thus, there are more than finitely many numbers between endpoint numbers not just along the way but even at its limit.

Comment: What segments are in the Cantor set?

Comment: Countably infinite numbers of segments with a calculated length of 0 but with more than finite numbers of number points between the endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

The standard proof that the limit of a convergent sequence is unique goes as follows.

> **Definition**: A sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to a limit $L$ if, for **any** open set $U$ containing $L$, all but finitely-many points in the sequence are contained in $U$.
>
> **Claim**: If $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L_1$ and also to $L_2$, then $L_1 = L_2$.
>
> **Proof**: Let $\{a_n\}$ converge to both $L_1$ and $L_2$ and define $\delta = |L_1-L_2|$. If $\delta>0$, then $I_1=(L_1-\delta/2, L_1+\delta/2)$ and $I_2=(L_2-\delta/2,L_2+\delta/2)$ are open sets containing $L_1$ and $L_2$, respectively. In this case, since $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L_1$, infinitely many of the $a_n$ must lie in $I_1$. However, since $I_1\cap I_2 = \emptyset$, that means that infinitely many $a_n$ must lie *outside* of $I_2$. This is a contradiction, since we said that $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L_2$. Therefore, we must conclude that $\delta=0$, meaning that $L_1 = L_2$.

This proof is very straightforward and (hopefully) easy to follow. Your proposed counterexample is not - it relies on some misconceptions (e.g. *"However, my argument holds because Cantor set is not a set along the way but the limit set, and there are more than finitely many numbers **between the endpoints in each segment in this limit set** even though the length is calculated as 0."* The limit set does not contain endpoints, because it does not consist of intervals).

However, rather than engaging with this and other issues with your proposed example, I would suggest you find a way to show that the simple proof written above fails, since it *must* fail if you are able to produce a counterexample.

Comment: In the previous posting (4857198) “ convergence divergence - The limit of a converging sequence is not unique. - Mathematics Stack Exchange “, I showed that the proof of the proposition that the limit of a converging sequence is flawed. The posting excited comments, and please read the debate to the end.

Comment: The fact that the proof is flawed does not mean that the proposition itself is flawed. Thus, this current posting is to present a counterexample of the proposition to show that the proposition itself is flawed, thus to show that the limit of a converging sequence is not unique.

Comment: @user1286486 I understand what you are trying to do. However, it is clear from your post that you are being confused by some of the subtleties involved in constructing the Cantor set. It appears, for example, that you think there is a meaningful notion of "segment" or "endpoint" in the Cantor set, which is not true. You are also invoking measure theory, which is yet more sophisticated. 

In order to avoid all of this, I provided an *extremely* simple proof of the uniqueness of the limit of a convergent sequence. In order for your proposed counterexample to *possibly* be correct [...]

Comment: [...] the proof I provided must be wrong. If you can find an error, then please point it out. However, I suspect you will find that you cannot find a mistake in the proof, and the correctness of the proof implies that your counterexample cannot be valid.

Comment: What we are examining is whether {an} converges to a single number or to a clump of numbers, a very tiny segment in the real number line. We can examine it by measuring the distance between each number among a clump of numbers which can be infinitely many.

Comment: To answer your asking:
If {an} converges to a clump of numbers which includes L1 and L2, then infinitely many {an} can be in either I1 or I2 when I1 ∩ I2 = ∅. That infinitely many {an} lie outside of I2 when {an} converges to L2 is not a contradiction because {an} converges not just to L2 but to a clump of numbers which includes both L1 and L2 as a part of the clump. Thus, it is not a contradiction which was to prove L1 = L2. Thus, there is a flaw in the proof.

Comment: @user1286486 So to be re-emphasize, infinitely many points lying outside $I_2$ means that the sequence does not converge to $L_2$  **by definition**. That is a contradiction. You are inventing words and concepts like convergence to a “clump” without defining what that means, or proving that such a thing makes any sense, in an effort to escape a fact that is routinely given as the first homework assignment in a first course in analysis. I am not interested in further engagement, but I’m sure with some careful thought you will come to terms with this. Best of luck with your studies.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in pointing out that I am wrong in stating that “infinitely many {an} lie outside of I2 when {an} converges to L2 is not a contradiction”. I am mistaken. It is too bad to lose the momentum by the mistake.
But I would like to add the following.

Comment: I tried to stay away from infinitesimal in the discussion and missed. Infinitesimal involves a lengthy discussion on what is infinitesimal, how its arithmetic differs from that of real numbers and is considered non-standard. 
A very rough sketch without details is as follows. Discussion with details is not possible here.
Because δ = |L1- L2| is infinitesimal, I1 = I2 by the arithmetic of infinitesimal which is different from that of real numbers. Thus, I1 ∩ I2 ≠ ∅. Thus, the proof based on I1 ∩ I2 = ∅ is problematic.

Comment: Professor Hodges mentioned in his 1998 paper, “It was surprising how many of our authors failed to realise that to attack an argument, you must find something wrong in it. Several authors believed that you can avoid a proof by simply doing something else “.
Thus, I would like to ask whether there is a flaw in my reasoning in the prior posting. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857198/the-limit-of-a-converging-sequence-is-not-unique .